# Is there any way to disable autocomplete for certain extension functions?

Tags: autocomplete, kotlin

For example, we have extension functions with too broad receivers (String). Is there any way to hide such extensions from autocomplete (annotation), so it will be required to manually import these extensions?

Answer (score 4):

First, the simplest solutions, you can scope your extensions in the following ways:

- Member extensions (declared inside a class) are only visible inside their class.
- Top level, private extensions are only visible within the given file.
- Top level, internal extensions are only visible in the given module.

---

You can also use IntelliJ tooling for this if the above doesn't fit your needs. For any given extension, you can start typing its name and choose it in autocomplete, and then invoke intention actions on it (<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>⌥↩</kbd> on macOS, or by clicking the lightbulb) to get the following menu:

[image: Intention actions on an autocomplete suggestion]

This will take you to a popup window with auto import settings (this is also available in the regular Settings menu under `Editor -> General -> Auto import`):

[image: Auto import settings]

What you need here are the Java specific settings, and as you can see among other options you can exclude classes, packages, or just single functions, either scoped to the current project or the entire IDE.

Comment: Wow, never though I could exclude completion items like this. There's a lot of those I'd gladly filter out. :)

Comment: is it possible to share the list of excluded functions with other teammates (store under VCS)?

Comment: It is! If you make the exclusions project scoped, they are placed in the `codeInsightSettings.xml` file under the `.idea` folder.